# submit form using checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form using jQuery. My code so far

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#display").on("change", "input:checkbox", function () {
        $("#display").submit();
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<form id="display">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hd" value="1"
        <?php
        if ($_SESSION['hd'] == 1) {
            echo "checked=\"checked\"";
        }
        ?>>HD
    <input type="checkbox" name="sd" value="1"
        <?php
        if ($_SESSION['sd'] == 1) {
            echo "checked=\"checked\"";
        }
        ?>>SD
</form>
```

The submit functions works fine but it does not retain the values in the form, it seems the submit is fired before values are assigned. What can be done?

Comment: On behalf of developers everywhere, can you please stop writing massive oneliners of jQuery? It makes for some the least legible code ever. And for the sake of everybody trying to help you, can you break your `<form>` down into readable nested HTML?

Comment: People don't expect checkboxes to submit forms. Use a submit button instead.

Comment: Use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to make your JS code readable next time please. =]

Comment: Agree with @Quentin. If you want to display two options and have choosing one or the other submit your form, you should be using two submit buttons.

Answer (score 2):

> it seems the submit is fired before values are assigned

Are checking `$_SESSION[]` for your value? This simply won't get set from a form submission.  You likely mean `$_POST['hd']`.

Comment: There is no option to use a "submit" button. The server side processing is fine, except the submit is fired before the SD or HD changes. I tried searching but could not find a solution.

Comment: @Truth - Because the OP is saying the values are not retained, surely they mean server side.

Comment: @daydreamer: If there's no option to a submit button, something is really wrong at your side.

Comment: @daydreamer - Can you explain **why** a submit button is not an option?

Comment: Really sorry if I am not clear. 
The form submits the values for HD and SD and it is part of a larger sql query. $sql = "SELECT from x where hd = '$hd' OR sd = '$sd'"
Everything works fine on the sql end but the correct values for HD and SD are not passed with form submit. Initially SD and HD are set to 1 and they remain 1 even if unchecked print_r($_POST) shows them 1.

Comment: @edmondson - The design of the whole area is such that a submit button cannot be added. Its more of a design issue than a functional issue.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you actually using `$print_r($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST['hd'])` to check the values?  Also you need to be really careful about sticking these values directly into a query.

Comment: [code]
    if (!isset($_SESSION['hd'])) $_SESSION['hd'] = 1;if (!isset($_SESSION['sd'])) $_SESSION['sd'] = 1;
[code]
and then
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' {
    $hd = sanitize($_POST['hd']); if ($hd == 1) $_SESSION['hd'] = 1; else $_SESSION['hd'] = 0;
    $sd = sanitize($_POST['sd']); if ($sd == 1) $_SESSION['sd'] = 1; else $_SESSION['sd'] = 0;
    }

Comment: @daydreamer - Like I said, session will not contain your form data because **it's not the POSTed** data.

Comment: @m.edmondson - Sorry i am not able to get the formatting corrected. The post and $_SESSION are fine. It's when the jQuery submits the form, it does not consider the checked or unchecked but always submits the original status.